# A question on vertical spring mass systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, spring

> For a given mass attached to a vertical spring (near the surface of the earth), how do we know that the equilibrium point is halfway between its oscillation? (Let the height at the bottom of oscillation = 0.)

What I know:

At the equilibrium point, acceleration = 0, so $mg=kx$, where $x$ is the displacement between point of release and point of equilibrium.

How can I move on from here?

Comment: Your question cannot be answered unless you define what $x$ is.  The complication being that you have defined a datum (reference position) for the height which cannot be the datum for $x$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, $x$ is the difference between the point of release to equilibrium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mass was displaced a further distance $dx$ so the extension is $x+\delta x$ then the restoring force is $F = k(x+\delta x) - mg = kx + k \delta x -kx = k\delta x$

towards the equilibrium position.

The restoring force is proportional to the distance from the equilibrium position and that's the condition for SHM.

In SHM the extremes of the oscillation are equally spaced either side of the equilibrium position.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting confused :( . Does the $x$ mean an extension or the $δx$?

Comment: @  Shooting Stars  the $x$ I took to mean the extension of the spring when the mass was hung on it (and allowed to settle), then if it's displaced by a further $dx$ from there, it'll do the SHM about the equilibrium position (with extension of the spring $x$)

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Overall you have made the problem more difficult by making the statement *Let the height at the bottom of oscillation = 0*.  Choosing the datum as the equilibrium position is the more usual way.

In the way you have formulated the question the diagram below shows: the unextended spring (natural length), the system (spring & mass) at equilibrium, the system when the mass is highest (Up) and the system when the mass is lowest (Down).

[image]

Equation energies at the very top and the very bottom gives,  $mg(y+y_0) + \frac 12 k (x-Y)^2 = \dfrac 12 k (x+y_0)^2$ which together with $mg = kx$ will produce the result that $Y=y_0$ ie the motion is symmetrical about the equilibrium position.

Comment: I was referring to it as a reference point( as we are only interested in the change in energies), hence what I am saying is the same as you.